# ICommand predicate not being read when updating property

Tags: c#, wpf, icommand

In an application I'm using for control of one or more devices on a serial communication bus, I'm using an `IsAlive` property in my `DeviceModel` class to tell if the communication link with the device is up (i.e. replies are received on the expected address).  The property fires a `PropertyChanged` event notification.

I'm using the `IsAlive` property both for setting the background color on a data template and for controlling the command predicate for the buttons in the data template.  By yanking out the communication cable, I'm forcing the link to time out and set `IsAlive` to false.  This works fine on the template background color, but the buttons aren't responding on the predicate change until I click anywhere on the View.

Any idea why this is?  And how I can get the buttons to update immediately when setting the `IsAlive` property?

C# command predicate:

```
private bool CanPressMovementButton(object obj) {
    if (IsAlive == true && Address > -1 && Address < 31) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here's a screenshot where the buttons are disabled even though the `IsAlive` property is set `true`.  The buttons are enabled immediatly when I click the View.

[image]

Comment: Are you using threading anywhere? Sounds like a threading issue.

Comment: Try to call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` on your DelegateCommand directly to notify all subscribers about state change

Comment: Not in other way than instantiating a DeviceModel object for every device, three in the case of the screenshot.  The command actions and predicates are part of the DeviceModel object.  Can this be the cause?

Comment: @AntonSemenov I'm using a `CustomCommand` implementation from this course (https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/practical-mvvm/table-of-contents) which doesn't have a RaiseCanExecuteChanged method.  Can you recommend an ICommand implementation that has this?

Comment: You should be able to raise this event though : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecutechanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Oystein Sorry, forget to mention Prism. actually you can find implementation of `DelegateCommand` by Microsoft in Prism library https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx or you can rase events with `CanExecuteChanged ` as Fildor mentioned.

Comment: Sometimes I find myself firing an `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the command property name and WPF obidiently re-evaluates the `CanExecute`. However, I'm not sure if this is anything close to a recommended way of handling the issue and I also don't know how stable this approach is.

Comment: @AntonSemenov Thanks for the tip.  I got it to work now using DelegateCommand and RaiseCanExecuteChanged().  Can you add your suggestion as an answer, so I can mark it?

Comment: @grek40 The notification works fine, as you can see from the datatemplate changing background color.  The problem was the view not reevaluating the command predicate when firing the notification.  It worked by calling the RaiseCanExecuteChanged() method.

Comment: Rather than edit the question to add the solution, post it as answer! [Answering your own question is not forbidden](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250208/4733879) (there is even an option to answer the question directly at the [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page)

Comment: @chade_ Yes, I could do that. Just thought I would give credit where credit is due.

Comment: @Oystein my suggestion is not an answer indeed. You've provided a real answer. So you can mark it as answer after several days )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [Anton Semenov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592835/anton-semenov)'s tip about using the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method in Prism's DelegateCommand implementation, it worked like a charm.  Setting `IsAlive` from the model now updates the View immediately without any need to give focus to the View.  Since I'll be supporting several device types with different commands depending on device type, I'm setting the `DelegateCommand` objects like this:

```
public bool IsAlive {
    get { return _isAlive; }
    set {
        bool newValue = SetNotify(ref _isAlive, value);
        if (newValue) {
            var properties = GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var property in properties) {
                if (property != null && property.PropertyType == typeof(DelegateCommand)) {
                    var command = (DelegateCommand)property.GetValue(this, null);
                    command.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                    Console.WriteLine("Raised!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that you can use the `.ObservesProperty` method when you instantiate your `DelegateCommand`s. When you use it, it subscribes to the `PropertyChanged` event and listens for that property automatically. This will help tidy up your `set`ter for your property, and allow you to better control which of your commands rely on which properties.